# How do I update the canvas and call asynchronous methods inside the setInterval function?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Okay here's a better example from: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_component_move ... My question is how do I move the red rectangle first upwards by calling myGamePiece.moveUp(); and AFTER it to the right by calling myGamePiece.moveRight();? because at the moment it happens simultaniously.

Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style>
        canvas {
            border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

    var myGamePiece;

    function startGame() {
        myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 250);
        myGameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function() {
            this.canvas.width = 480;
            this.canvas.height = 270;
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
        },
        clear : function() {
            this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        }
    }

    function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.update = function(){
            ctx = myGameArea.context;
            ctx.fillStyle = color;
            ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
        };

        this.moveUp = function () {
          if(this.y > 50) {
              this.y -= 1;
          }
        };

        this.moveRight = function () {
            if(this.x < 400) {
                this.x += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
        myGameArea.clear();
        myGamePiece.moveUp();
        myGamePiece.moveRight();
        myGamePiece.update();
    }
</script>
<p>The red square moves one pixel to the right, 50 times per second.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you calling interval each interval? instead do `setInterval(update, 1000/fps);` where fps is a desired framerate. and remove "interval();" from update function. Also, could you be more precise with your question?

Comment: I agree with the @TomaszRadwaski. And, we don't know what do you want to do. Please be more clear.

Comment: I have edited it now, I want the moveUp and moveRight methods to be called asynchronous. And I want them to be used multiple for example call the moveUp method to move 50px upwards and by calling it again the object should move 50px upwards again from the new Position on the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    canvas {
      border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="startGame()">
  <script>
    var myGamePiece;

    function startGame() {
      myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 250);
      myGameArea.start();
    }

    var myGameArea = {
      canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
      start: function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        var onclick = document.createAttribute("onclick");
        onclick.value = "getMousePosition(event)";
        this.canvas.setAttributeNode(onclick);
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
      },
      clear: function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
      }
    };

    function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
      this.targetx = undefined;
      this.targety = undefined;
      this.width = width;
      this.height = height;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
      };

      this.moveUp = function() {
        this.y -= 1;
      };

      this.moveRight = function() {
        this.x += 1;
      };

      this.moveDown = function() {
        this.y += 1;
      };

      this.moveLeft = function() {
        this.x -= 1;
      };
    }

    function updateGameArea() {
      myGameArea.clear();
      if (myGamePiece.targetx && myGamePiece.targetx) {
        if (myGamePiece.targetx < myGamePiece.x) {
          myGamePiece.moveLeft();
        } else if (myGamePiece.targetx > myGamePiece.x) {
          myGamePiece.moveRight();
        } else if (myGamePiece.targety < myGamePiece.y) {
          myGamePiece.moveUp();
        } else if (myGamePiece.targety > myGamePiece.y) {
          myGamePiece.moveDown();
        } else {
          myGamePiece.targety = undefined;
          myGamePiece.targetx = undefined;
        }
      }
      myGamePiece.update();

    }

    function getMousePosition(event) {
      var x = event.clientX;
      var y = event.clientY;
      var coords = "X coords: " + x + ", Y coords: " + y;
      console.log(coords);
      myGamePiece.targetx = x;
      myGamePiece.targety = y;
    }
  </script>
  <p>The red square moves one pixel to the right, 50 times per second.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

What I understood is that you want to do this. Move one up then one right then one up then one right. This is how you can do that. Small differences. EDIT: I understood wrong. I am editing the code now. EDIT2: Added the functionality you asked. EDIT3: UPDATED CODE to make it move where the mouse clicks. Warning. Due to the way the object is rendered on screen it the object does not move exactly centered where you want to go. I recommend to use p5.js framework to handle canvas and not pure javascript. Search for "the coding train" on youtube for tutorials.

Comment: It's almost the solution, however I want to call the moveUp method multiple times. For example the object should be able to moveUp twice... first from the starting position by calling moveUp for the first time and after it from the new Position by calling moveUp again.

Comment: I edited the code just 30 seconds ago. Try it again. I am the same person that made the other answer.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I looked for.

Comment: Ι recommend using p5.js. Read the edit3. It has all this functions integrated. This whole game could be created in less than 20-25 lines using p5 with easy events for keyboard and mouse and VERY easy drawing of objects on canvas :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want it moving separately, you should have two different `setInterval`*. Otherwise, things will change so fast that it will look like it happened at the same time.

Another possible solution is to make `x` and `y` animating after specific events, like key press or mouse movement.

- I also suggest you take a look at `window.requestAnimationFrame()`

Comment: What do you mean by two different setInterval? I looked up window.requestAnimationFrame(), but I couldn't find a solution to my problem... look at the second example from w3schools, then you will understand my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all what you are looking for is setTimeout and not interval since what you are essentially doing is calling interval() many times. If you dont want the object to move diagonally you should create two seperate functions that have their own timers

Comment: Could you give me an example or change the sample code please?

Comment: What do you want to do? Move x by 1 after 2 secs then y by 1 after 2 secs then x by 1 after 2 secs and so on?

Comment: Could you change the second example, which I gave from w3schools? I want the moveUp() Method to change the Y-position of the rect every second by 1 till it reaches 50 and after it the moveRight() Method to change X-position every second by 1 till it reaches 400. Thanks.

Comment: When you say after it, you want to first completely move 50 blocks up and then start moving right?

Comment: Yes! That's right, I want to move 50 blocks up and then from there (the new position) I want to move right. There will be also a method for moving left and down, but first I need to know how to do it...

Comment: It's almost what I wanted, however I thought that there would be a way to change the method moveUp() so that I can move from anywhere 50 blocks up or move from anywhere 50 blocks right... Because at the moment I can use moveUp() or moveRight just once. If you could give me the solution for this, then I will be happy. Thanks.

Comment: This is possible but how are you gonna command it to move? Do you want to control the object with the keyboard arrows?

Comment: I added exactly what you asked but it starts moving immediately. No button to start.